# RegEx for 4 values within a link (This or this or this etc)

Tags: java, regex

Having a bit of trouble with this.

Say I have a link that could contain these values:

`Balearic|Ibiza|Majorca|Menorca`

Example1: `http://site.com/Menorca`

Example2: `http://site.com/Ibiza`

I just need a RegEx to say if the link contains any of those 4 (case insensitive as well)

Can someone point in the right direction - it is not in a particular language but the software I work in is Java based.

Thanks a lot - and I'll keep trying in the meantime! :)

Comment: http://rubular.com/r/IYWIUc3Z98

Comment: You might consider matching for `Mallorca` as well since it's an acceptable alternative spelling...

Comment: @ctn - cool regex test site! I'm bookmarking it...

Comment: Is it your intention that the regex should match `http://site.com` in particular - I would have thought you'd want it to match any domain, and `http` as well as `https` - but that is not how people responding so far have interpreted your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use:

```
// assuming url is your URL variable
if (url.matches("(?i)^http://site\.com/(Balearic|Ibiza|Majorca|Menorca)\b.*$")) {
   // match succeeded
}
```

`(?i)` will make sure case is ignored while doing this comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Your list of values *is* a valid regex, just add the "i" option to make it case insensitive, per http://rubular.com/r/euscuu7Fwj

Answer (score 0):

[Here you can find](http://www.debuggex.com/r/nSoO3ZyU6o57LYSG) a regexp that matches what you ask:

```
^http://site\.com/(Balearic|Ibiza|Majorca|Menorca)$
```

[image: Regular expression image]

to use it in Java, you may want to do the following:

```
String url = "http://site.com/Ibiza";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^http://site\.com/(Balearic|Ibiza|Majorca|Menorca)$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(url); // get a matcher object
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually regex against URL is not a good practice.

Here's a mixed approach. It will look for your values only in the path of your URLs, thus both simplifying the regular expression and validating the URL. Case-insensitive.

```
try {
    URI menorca = new URI("http://site.com/Menorca");
    System.out.println(menorca.getPath().substring(1));
    URI ibiza = new URI("http://site.com/Ibiza");
    System.out.println(ibiza.getPath().substring(1));
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Balearic|Ibiza|Majorca|Menorca", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    System.out.println(pattern.matcher(menorca.getPath()).find());
    System.out.println(pattern.matcher(ibiza.getPath()).find());
}
catch (URISyntaxException use) {
    use.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output:

```
Menorca
Ibiza
true
true
```